# Use param name when calling function with all default parameters in C++

Tags: c++, function, coding-style

In C++, if I have a function with all default parameters:

```
void foo(int a = 9, int b = 3);
```

Can I call it with param names? Like:

```
foo(b = 5);
```

When I search online, seems one can not bypass the first param and specify the value of the second param.

The thing is I want to have a function to init a struct. It accepts values for random amount of the struct members, then init other members with default value. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look up the Boost Parameter Library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it directly, since c++ supports by-order arguments in function calls.

You can achieve your goal with creating a struct with setters that return itslef by reference, then you can just chain your calls:

```
MyStruct s;
s.set_a(8).set_b(3453).set_whatever("Hellow world");
```

Read more on Builder design pattern [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#C.2B.2B_Example) (+example).

Or, if you are insisting on by-name function arguments, you can try [boost parameter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html) library.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into boost library.